# DbSet does not have an async method for remove range?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I can't find an async version of RemoveRange. It exists, for example, for `AddRange`. Anyone knows why? It seems odd to me not to have an homogeneous set of commands.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it is synchronous operation and providing fake `Async` method which runs synchronously and returns completed task would be misleading and against async method principles.

EF Core provides async versions only for methods which potentially access database - e.g. `Add{Range}`, `Find`, `SaveChanges`, `Dispose`, and sync only version for methods which operate purely on state (change tracker) like `Attach{Range}`, `Update{Range}`, `Remove{Range}`.

As of why `Add{Range}` have async version, the reason is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-3.1):

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo`, to access the database asynchronously.